# Odd sound after tire rotation?

Tags: chevrolet, tires, cobalt

About two days ago I got my `tires rotated` on my `2005 Chevy Cobalt` while I was getting an oil change. This was the first time that the tires had been rotated in at least 14,000 miles (since I purchased the car). The car itself has about 36,000 miles, so I'd assume that's the age of the tires.

Anyways, whenever I go above 30 mph I hear a helicopter like sound, and it ramps up the faster I go.

Here's two videos I've recorded:

1. http://youtu.be/bb0gZGLJJ5M
2. http://youtu.be/Ol6MMqPVfgQ

I've read that it can be caused by waiting too long to get the tires rotated, as they start to wear into a pattern, which can cause the noise.

Comment: you could always rotate them back to see if it goes away :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you are describing is exactly what it sounds like is happening. Tires which are not rotated on a regular basis will complain loudly because of wear patterns, especially the front end ones on front wheel drive vehicles. If those are original tires, I would bet they are getting close to being worn out. Tires which are getting down in tread depth will make more noise as well. The less tread, the more noise (usually).

Answer (score 0):

Rotated or swopped back to front? Check on the tyres side wall for the word 'Rotation'. There will also be an arrow or indicater for the direction of rotation when driving forward. They must be on the correct side of the vehicle and rotating in a forward direction. The age of your tyres can be found by reading the DOT code on the tyre wall. You will see the word 'DOT' next to a box with four numbers within it. The first two numbers are for 'the week of the year', whilst the second two numbers are for 'year of manufacture'. ie. DOT 2414 would mean twenty-fourth week of 2014, which is when the tyre was produced.