# Loud "tire hum" at highway speeds after tire rotation where I also let a jack down too fast

Tags: tires, noise

I rotated my tires myself a few weeks ago and afterwards, the first time I got on the freeway, there was significant louder-than-usual tire noise.  I would describe it as a loud constant vibration hum, not a squeal, and it gets worse the higher the speed (starting at about 55mph).  It's not just a little, it's to the point where I feel unsafe on the freeway with it, like something is going to break at any moment at high speed.

Is one possibility because I didn't get the tires balanced?  I also topped off the tire pressure, so it's also got a few more PSI in it than before.  I don't think they are directional-tread tires, but I suppose another possibility is that they are and I've got them on the wrong sides now.

[Another question seems to indicate that tire rotation with worn tires can produce excess noise after rotation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12242/odd-sound-after-tire-rotation).

I'm willing to take this in to the tire shop to get the tires balanced or replaced altogether if they tell me they're too worn.  But before I commit to the new tires, there's another component to this that is my main question:

When I did the tire rotation myself, I had a brain malfunction and dropped the jack way too quick (the jack was on the passenger side, but I don't recall if it was front or back).  The car on one corner had a hard landing and I did hear a "crunching" noise.  And I know that probably means I did some damage, potentially serious. (Amateur hour, I know.)

What is the kind of damage I might have done by dropping the jack too fast?  Did I maybe bend or crack a wheel or...worse?

Who would be the best to diagnose this kind of potential damage?  Is my local tire shop the best place to diagnose, or should I take it to my general mechanic?

Vehicle: mid-2000s Mazda 3 hatchback, automatic

Comment: Just a side note: if you want to learn if rotating the tires was the cause of the new noise, rotate the tires back to where they came from and see if the noise goes away. It's free, it's easy and at least you'll know what you're dealing with. If the tires are directional, they will have an arrow on the sidewall showing which way they should rotate.

Comment: Does the sound come from a particular wheel? If so, investigate that wheel and everything around it as it sounds like rubbing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the humming noise, the answer link you posted should be the answer to your inquiry.

As far as any damage for dropping the corner hard, if the lugs were at least snug (even hand tightened) when you did the "deed", really there shouldn't be much to worry about. The suspension, wheels, tires, and connecting parts are more than capable of a small little fall like you described. I couldn't tell you what the noise you heard was, but realistically, there's nothing to worry about. Car suspensions can take much harder hits and have zero damage. Think of how many potholes you've hit at speed and suffered no damage. What you're describing is much less of a hit than that is.

Even if the lugs weren't completely tight, there's little chance of any damage. If you are not feeling any pulling or handling issues, I doubt there is anything to worry about.